# How to can solve index error of concrete?

Tags: python, tensorflow, index-error

An error occurred while studying the acquisition of the concrete function.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Inc(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs + 1
inc = Inc()

inc_g2 = tf.function(inc)

concrete_fun = inc_g2.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, 3),
                dtype=tf.float32))
print(concrete_fun(tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])))
```

Error Message:
**IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have no error running this code. Maybee another unshown part of it is returning the error message ?
Then give more details, and a minimal reproducible example with code you wrote yet / sample data / and full error messages about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help. See [MRE]

Answer (score 0):

To get the output of `get_concrete_function`, the function must be of type `tf.function`, but you are trying to use the concrete function to get the output. Please find the working code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Inc(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs + 1
inc = Inc()

inc_g2 = tf.function(inc)

inc_g2.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, 3),
                dtype=tf.float32))
print(inc_g2(tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])))
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([[2. 3. 4.]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
```